# Disable sys_file_reference_field only for pages table

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-9.x

I have added a checkbox to sys_file_reference and utilize it to override some responsive fluid rendering. Works fine. Now I would like to disable this checkbox in the pages media field. Normally disabling fields is easily done via page typoscript

`TCEFORM.TABLENAME.FIELDNAME.disabled = 1`

However since the sys_file_reference is used in both pages and tt_content this won't work since it globally disables it:

`TCEFORM.sys_file_reference.myfield.disabled = 1`

I know I can disable fields for certain CTypes by using this syntax:

`TCEFORM.tt_content.myfield.types.textmedia.disabled = 1`

Is there something similar for tables instead of types? I unsuccessfully tried

`TCEFORM.sys_file_reference.myfield.tables.pages.disabled = 1`

`TCEFORM.pages.myfield.disabled = 1`

`TCEFORM.pages.tables.sys_file_reference.myfield.disabled = 1`

`TCEFORM.pages.myfield.tables.sys_file_reference.disabled = 1`

`TCEFORM.pages.myfield.types.sys_file_reference.disabled = 1`

Or do I need to do this in the PHP TCA Override?

thanks

Comment: instead of `TCEFORM.tt_content...` you can use `TCEFORM.pages...`.

Comment: I did try that, but since that is not the table I'm working on it doesnt help. I added some more examples that I tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In TCA config you can override the childs config for an specific field. So you can set the child TCA (sys_file_reference) of media for a field as type `passthrough` to make it hidden:

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['pages']['columns']['media']['config']['overrideChildTca']['columns']['myfield'] = [
    'config' => [
        'type' => 'passthrough'
    ]
];
```

See the [TCA Reference](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/master/en-us/ColumnsConfig/Type/Inline.html#overridechildtca) for more information.

Comment: Thanks, this comment got me in the right direction. two things though:
1) the correct setting is 
    ````$GLOBALS['TCA']['pages']['columns']['media']['config']['overrideChildTca']['columns']['myfield'] = ````
  please edit this so i can make your answer the accepted answer
2) if you use a custom renderType you need to make that passthrough instead of type, otherwise the field will still get rendered

Comment: thanks for you hint @JaNosch, I have edited the array declaration